# Understanding methods in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to Java.This was a example on OOP.I have a class file named **"Automobile.java"** and the driver program saved as **AutomobileTest.java**.My question is when a object is created in AutomobileTest.java  how  does it know that it has to access the methods and variables from Automobile.java.
This is my code:
**Automobile.java**

```
class Automobile{
    public int numWheels;
    public String colour;
    public boolean engineRunning;
    public double mileage;
    public int numSeats;


    public Automobile(int wheels,int seats,String vehicleColour){
        numWheels=wheels;
        numSeats=seats;
        colour=vehicleColour;
        engineRunning=false;
        mileage=0.0;    
    }

    public void startEngine(){
         engineRunning=true;
    }
    public void stopEngine(){
         engineRunning=false;
    }
    public double drive(double numMiles){
        return mileage+=numMiles;

    }
    public String toString(){
        String s="numWheels="+numWheels+"\nNumber of seats = "+numSeats+ "\nColour:" +colour+ "\nEngineRunning: " + engineRunning;
        return s;
    }
}
```

**AutomobileTest.java**

```
public class AutomobileTest{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Automobile ferrari=new Automobile(4,2,"red");
        System.out.println(ferrari);
        System.out.println("Engine started");
        ferrari.startEngine();
        System.out.println(ferrari);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Access specifier...

Comment: I highly suggest starting with a beginner's book on Java or the tutorials from Oracle. They answer these questions and more.

Comment: go to the link.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm

Comment: because you've created object represented by _Automobile.java_ (`Automobile class`)

Comment: I suggest you to read Head First java and your will get your answer. But for now , You are creating object of AutomoBile class in your AutoMobileTest.java.

Comment: You don't have a class file `Automobile.java`. You have a source file of that name. To get a class file `Automobile.class` you need to compile it first. Note, this is not nitpicking, it is important to get not confused about what is what.

Comment: Because a) you created a new Automobile (called `ferrari`) in AutomobileTest, and b) the methods and variables in Automobile are public, therefore you can call them from other classes (e.g. by doing `ferrari.startEngine()`)

Comment: Strange question. It “knows” because you told it so. Maybe you try to explain what you think could stop it from “knowing”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how the contents of `AutomobileTest.java` knows to find the `Automobile` class in `Automobile.java`, this has to do with Java packaging.

In Java, you can declare classes to be of a certain package by saying `package X` at the top of multiple Java source files. This means that they will share a "namespace", and thus have access to methods and variables (subject the access modifiers that other commenters are mentioning, such as `public` and `private`).

But it seems like your files don't say `package X` at the top. Well, by default Java puts files in the same directory in the "anonymous package", so technically `Automobile.java` and `AutomobileTest.java`  share a namespace.

For more information about Java packages, see these resources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Answer (score 2):

From your question I totally understand that you are new to Java programming.

To answer your question, in the AutomobileTest.java file, you have included the statement

```
Automobile ferrari=new Automobile(4,2,"red");
```

in this line, the keyword "new" will tell the java compiler to create a object of the class Automobile and thus java compiler will know which class to access.

To know more about this, you need to do a lot of study. Refer  [this](http://www.sahyadri.edu.in/SMCA/students_guide/3semnotes/java/Java%20The%20Complete%20Reference,%207th%20Edition.pdf)  book.

Answer (score 1):

It knows, because they are in the same package. Read about packages and access protection [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_access_protection).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✔
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✘
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
no modifier |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✘     |   ✘
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
private     |  ✔    |    ✘    |    ✘     |   ✘
```